# Grails 1.3.7 not starting with JBoss 7.1

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss7.x

My company is trying to upgrade from `JBoss` 4.2.3 to `JBoss` 7. Currently I've setup a local copy of `JBoss` 7.1 and am trying to get my grails project to work on `JBoss` 7.1
The exact same war works just fine in `JBoss` 4.2.3. The weird thing is that there aren't any errors. Here is the info from the startup:

```
    Calling "C:\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.0\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.0

  JAVA: C:\Java\jdk7\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.cl
ient.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman

===============================================================================

15:02:53,200 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.0.GA
15:02:53,414 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:02:53,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final-SNAPSHOT "Flux Capacitor" starting
15:02:54,062 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.0.GA
15:02:54,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-h
ttp)
15:02:54,075 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.GA
15:02:54,082 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.GA
15:02:54,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
15:02:54,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:02:54,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
15:02:54,133 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:02:54,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
15:02:54,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Exten
sion
15:02:54,145 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsy
stem
15:02:54,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
15:02:54,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacam
ar 1.0.7.Final)
15:02:54,199 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
15:02:54,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Binding JAXR ConnectionFactory: java:jboss/jaxr/Connecti
onFactory
15:02:54,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deployi
ng JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
15:02:54,231 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/ma
il/Default]
15:02:54,254 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010404: Deployi
ng non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
15:02:55,312 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - S
tack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
15:02:55,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
15:02:55,434 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-15) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on ht
tp--127.0.0.1-8080
15:02:55,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data sourc
e [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
15:02:55,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS010400: Bound data sour
ce [java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS]
15:02:55,575 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
15:02:55,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDepl
oymentService for directory C:\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.0\standalone\deployments
15:02:55,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ServerC
onfig.war"
15:02:56,941 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBossOSGi Framework Core -
 1.1.1
15:02:56,975 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final-SNAPSHOT "Flux Capacitor" s
tarted (with errors) in 4090ms - Started 170 of 245 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 72 services are
 passive or on-demand)
15:02:57,047 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-10) Install bundle: system.bu
ndle:0.0.0
15:02:57,269 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-10) Install bundle: javax.api
:0.0.0
15:02:57,270 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-5) Install bundle: javax.tran
saction.api:0.0.0
15:02:57,270 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-12) Install bundle: jbosgi-re
pository-api:1.0.4
15:02:57,330 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-2) Install bundle: jboss-as-o
sgi-configadmin:7.1.0.Final-SNAPSHOT
15:02:57,348 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-3) Install bundle: jboss-osgi
-logging:1.0.0
15:02:57,378 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-8) Install bundle: org.apache
.felix.log:1.0.0
15:02:57,379 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Install bundle: org.apache
.felix.configadmin:1.2.8
15:02:57,378 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-11) Install bundle: jbosgi-ht
tp-api:1.0.5
15:02:57,535 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Install bundle: osgi.enter
prise:4.2.0.201003190513
15:02:57,931 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.StartLevelPlugin] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting bundles for st
art level: 1
15:02:57,936 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: osgi.ent
erprise:4.2.0.201003190513
15:02:57,941 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: javax.ap
i:0.0.0
15:02:57,952 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: jboss-os
gi-logging:1.0.0
15:02:57,959 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: javax.tr
ansaction.api:0.0.0
15:02:57,964 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: jbosgi-h
ttp-api:1.0.5
15:02:57,967 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: jbosgi-r
epository-api:1.0.4
15:02:57,984 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: org.apac
he.felix.configadmin:1.2.8
15:02:58,001 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: org.apac
he.felix.log:1.0.0
15:02:58,007 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bundle started: jboss-as
-osgi-configadmin:7.1.0.Final-SNAPSHOT
15:02:58,013 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.FrameworkActive] (MSC service thread 1-2) OSGi Framework started
15:02:58,030 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.BundleManager] (MSC service thread 1-12) Install bundle: ServerCon
fig:0.1.0
15:02:58,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "ServerConfig.war"
15:02:58,568 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState] (MSC service thread 1-14) Bundle started: ServerConfig:0.1.0
```

===============================================================================

I also checked the `JBoss 7` server.log and no errors were shown. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you check the console to see what it said about the WAR after you deployed it?

Comment: Yes, under Manage Deployments in the console ServerConfig.war shows up and the Enabled box is checked.  I couldn't find any other details about the war other than its enabled.

Comment: I just tried creating a blank grails project and then packaging it as a war using the "grails war" command. I deployed this blank project to JBoss 7.1 and it won't load either. Same deal, with no errors show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jboss 7 was trying to treat the application as an OSGI project rather than a regular web application.
The key was to either remove osgi from the grails project's manifest or disable it in Jboss 7 configuration. I wasn't able to find out how to disable it on the grails project's manifest so I removed osgi from Jboss 7.
You can remove it from Jboss 7 by opening up standalone.xml and finding the subsystem labelled as

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
...

...

</subsystem>
```

and either commenting this out or delete it.  I commented mine out and Jboss automatically deleted it for me after I restarted Jboss. Right after I did this my grails project was loaded  properly.

David

Comment: thanks for this solution. This did solve my upgrade issue as well. You should accept your own answer since it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set:

```
grails.project.war.osgi.headers = false
```

into BuildConfig.groovy.

See jboss discussion here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFK2-65